# Anchor Tags in Sharepoint Search Results

Tags: 2013, search-results, navigation, html, anchor-tags

It is planned to create a very long page with much content in our Sharepoint environment (a company manual).

This manual will be divided with headings with anchor tags in it, so that you can jump to each section without reloading it.

When the search finds something in one of the section. Is it possible to display the link in the search results with this HTML tag so that the page focuses the section and not the beginning of the page?